# Dovecot: missing +w perm: /var/mail, we're not in group 8(mail)

Tags: dovecot

I can't figure out what I am missing. I'm setting up a new mail server and had this erorre every time I receive an email.
The user is inside the group mail

```
mail:x:8:dovecot,user.name
```

The perms directory are here /var/mail

```
drwxrwsr-x  3 root mail   4096 nov 11 12:20 mail/
```

This is dovecot configuration

```
# 2.2.22 (fe789d2): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.13 (7b14904)
# OS: Linux 4.4.0-47-generic x86_64 Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS ext4
auth_mechanisms = plain login
mail_location = mbox:/var/mail/%u
namespace inbox {
  inbox = yes
  location =
  mailbox Drafts {
    special_use = \Drafts
  }
  mailbox Junk {
    special_use = \Junk
  }
  mailbox Sent {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox "Sent Messages" {
    special_use = \Sent
  }
  mailbox Trash {
    special_use = \Trash
  }
  prefix =
}
passdb {
  driver = pam
}
protocols = " imap pop3"
service auth {
  unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/auth {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
  }
}
ssl = no
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do you read [this documentation](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/MailLocation/mbox#A.2BAC8-var.2BAC8-mail.2BAC8_dotlocks)?

You must add

> mail_privileged_group = mail

Or make `/var/mail` world-writable with sticky bit set, allowing anyone to create new files but not overwrite or delete existing files owned by someone else

> chmod a+rwxt /var/mail

Comment: I did try the sticky bit but didn't work. Tryed with mail_privileged_group but same error after restarting dovecot. The only solution by now is to create the directory in /var/Mail by hand and give the user's owner. What a about a good solution?

Comment: @Kreker "*I did try the sticky bit but didn't work*" I'm not entirely sure I believe that.  Did you follow *all* the instructions with respect to the sticky bit (ie, world-writeable also)?

Comment: Yes of course. If you are using `mail_privileged_group = mail` all mail users must be in specified group.

Comment: ok this is working,after adding the new user to user mail. for some reason I have to reset the sticky bit. Sorry

Comment: The documentation link is broken. Can you update the link and perhaps also copy the relevant part into answer?

Answer (score 4):

In my own situation I've found that simply making sure that `/var/mail` is owned by the `mail` group and making sure that the user's group is set to `mail` as well is enough for this to work.

If you're sharing dovecot's authentication system with other services (IE: you're using `/etc/passwd` & `/etc/shadow` for user information and authentication instead of `/etc/mail/passwd` or some such), you'll want to at least make sure that the user has `mail` as *one* of its groups, even if it's not practical to make `mail` its primary group. In a shared authentication system scenario, you'll also want to have the mentioned `mail_privileged_group` parameter set to `mail` in `dovecot.conf`, or in one of its included configuration files like so:

```
mail_privileged_group = mail
```

I should also note that `0770` should be the highest privileges you need to give to `/var/mail`. dovecot will create the user's directory with user only write permissions after its created, so you don't have to worry about the group permissions getting inherited.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, in our Ispconfig mail server, the issue was only the executable permissions so giving the permissions to the directory fixed the error:

```
chmod +x /var/vmail/domain.com
```